# VBScript Regular Expression

Tags: regex, vbscript

Need help building a VBScript regex that checks for a valid computer name and returns only invalid characters.  String can contain numbers, upper and lower case letters, and (-) sign only.  It can't start or end with (-) and cannot be only numbers.

Valid (Returns no match):

> computer 
>   Computer8 
>   8Computer 
>   Com8puter 
>   Com-Puter 
>   Computer-123

Invalid (Returns a match to invalid characters):

> 123 
>   -computer 
>   computer- 
>   com*puter 
>   PC&123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up switching the valid and invalid returns.  I also ended up using two different RegEx strings.  The first is:

```
 ^[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}[-]*[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}$
```

This doesn't allow the (-) at the beginning or end and requires all numbers, letters, or (-).  It also requires a string of at least two characters.

The second is:

```
"[a-zA-Z]"
```

This makes sure there is at least one letter included.

Answer (score 2):

According to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx VBScript has its own regex syntactic flavour. Note that NetBIOS computer names have a length limit of 15.

Then it should be "^\w[\w-]{0,14}$"

That RegEx satisfies all of the requirements except the "is all numbers". That can be done by running a second regex "^\d+$".

In code:

```
Dim regexValid, regexNumber
Set regexValid = New RegExp
Set regexNumber = New RegExp

regexValid.Global = True
regexValid.IgnoreCase = True
regexNumber.Global = True
regexNumber.IgnoreCase = True

regexValid.Pattern = "^\w[\w\-]{0,14}$"
regexNumber.Pattern = "^\d+$"

Dim inputString
inputString = InputBox("Computer name?")

If regexValid.Test( inputString ) And Not regexNumber.Test( inputString ) Then
    ' It's a valid computer name string
Else
    ' It's invalid
End If
```

Hmm, this is the first VBScript I've written this year.

Comment: This was close.  In VBScript, \w also includes the _ however.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this `/^([0-9]|[a-zA-Z]){1,}[a-zA-Z0-9-]+([0-9]|[a-zA-Z]){1,}$/`